# How to use period in PARM parameters (JCL)?

Tags: mainframe, period, jcl, zos

The situation is the following.
I have PARM parameters:

```
CSQ1            - Queue manager name
CARD.PAYMENTS   - Request queue name
CCD3050.REPLY   - Reply queue name
CCD3050         - Contestant user ID
400.05          - Payment amount
"MY PAYMENT"    - Payment description
```

In my JCL I wrote this so:

```
//PAYMENT  EXEC PGM=PAYMENT,REGION=1024K,                               
//             PARM='CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,CCD3050.REPLY,CCD3050,          
//             400.05,"MY PAYMENT"'
```

I had a trouble. I wrote:

```
//             PARM=('CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,CCD3050.REPLY,CCD3050',
//             '400.05,MY PAYMENT')
```

And had a trouble too.
Then I wrote:

```
PARM=(CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,CCD3050.REPLY,CCD3050,400.05,MY PAYMENT)
```

- and!!!
  had this:
  **2 IEFC624I INCORRECT USE OF PERIOD IN THE PARM FIELD** 
  What does it mean?
  AND HOW IS CORRECT TO USE PERIODS IN JCL? I haven't found this info anywhere...
  Help please!

Comment: FYI, "_I had a trouble_" is a useless statement.  It doesn't say what you observed or what the system told you was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `.`, `=`, `,` `'` `(` `)`   (there may be more, I'm not trying to be exhastive) as part of the *value* of the PARM, then you need to ensure they don't get interpreted by the converter/interpreter.

You do this by bounding things with single quotes, or parenthesis, or you can have combinations of those, but if your PARM *values* contain such things you have to protect them (as you would `escape` something in other OSs, languages).

Here is a link a JCL Language Reference. You can follow the links inside the page to completely explore the manual, or download a PDF of it. http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/handheld/Connected/BOOKS/iea2b690/16.8.1?SHELF=&DT=20090526233806&CASE=

On another question of yours I have already shown you a PARM that can contain all those values.

```
// PARM=('CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,CCD3050.REPLY,CCD3050,400.05,MY PAYMENT')
```

or

```
//  PARM='CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,CCD3050.REPLY,CCD3050,400.05,MY PAYMENT'
```

Will work, as far as the JCL is concerned.

You can protect the `.`s in many different ways.

Those PARMs both fit on one line. They will be difficult to maintain. Put them in parenthesis, one element per line:

```
// PARM=(CSQ1,
//       'CARD.PAYMENTS',
//       'CCD3050.REPLY',
//       CCD3050,
//       '400.05',
//       'MY PAYMENT')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I've tried different variants - and no one worked..
JCL Language Reference I've already read, and made as there described - but had no result.